# Find a String in a txt-File, with a 10-million-character long String in it, and get the position of the searched String

Tags: string, parsing, search, position, text-files

The **10-million-character-long String**, where i want to find String-Patterns in,
is too big to just declare it as a constant. So i decided to "outsource" that string in a txt-file.
But how do I **get the Start-Position (Character-Position) of the searched string-pattern**? What is the best method or function to get a result if i had to **do this many times**? A more advanced search like KMP or BM is prefered but for testing not important. The coding-language could be in *Java(Script)* or a *PowerShell-Script*.

- The String in the txt-file is one BIG Number with 10 million digits. Only 0-9 no other chars.
- The String-Patterns I am looking for are Numbers with a variable number of digits (between 32 to maybe 4096 digits)
- The result-Position of all matches are written to a new txt-file.

I tried to insert that BIG string as a constant in Java, JavaScript for testing but it broke eclipse. (It just stopped working and I had to delete the Project-Folder to get eclipse working again)
Then I searched for other solutions like "Select-String" in PowerShell to find the String in my txt-file. It found a match but then PowerShell stopped working without showing any result.

*Even if i had to do this many times a one-time-task solution will help me to do several test-experiments.*

**Thank You!**

Comment: Please [edit] post to specify the programming language you want to see an answer in and *show* your research (i.e. how Wikipedia on string search did not help) as well as coding attempt in that language. Also clarify if you are looking for repeating searches or it is one-time task (as one-time task can be solved in couple lines with O(len_file * len_pattern) when for repeated searches you need O(len_file + len_pattern) provided by more advanced searches like KMP )

Answer (score 0):

I found a PowerShell solution:

```
Get-Content sample.txt | ForEach-Object {

  # Get the indices of all '0123456789' instances.
  $indices = [regex]::Matches($_, '0123456789').Index

  # Output them as a list (string), separated with spaces.
  "$indices"

}
```